# mysterious difference between rake test and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, scope

Here is the mysterious:

I have a scope which looks like this (in Image.rb)

```
  scope :moderate_all, delegates.where("moderation_flag = #{$moderation_flags[:not_moderated]}")
```

Note that delegates is another scope that I am defining before moderate_all

When I leave it like this, I can run my test that checks if an image has been "checked-out" it is not available anymore. I don't put the code of the test, because it does not matter actually.

With this code, when I run "rake test" it fails, but if I do "ruby test/unit/image_test.rb" it works! I was thinking I am starting to have a bad day. Then I tried

```
  scope :moderate_all, lambda {
    delegates.where("moderation_flag = #{$moderation_flags[:not_moderated]}")
  }
```

And "rake test" passes!

So my problem is solved, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$moderation_flags looks like a global, and  the value of the named scope depends on it. My guess is that rake test loads the class before the global is ready, but invoking the test directly goes the other way.

Introducing the lambda causes the where clause to be evaluated when the scope is used, so it always happens late when the global is ready.

Comment: You're so right! I did not think about the global variable load order. I have put 0 instead of my global variable and it works without the lambda

Comment: There is something weird though, is that I don't get any error, the test fails. The difference is that the number of record returned is different. Did the framework set the constant to a random value? I would think it would maybe, by default set the constant to 0. But 0 IS the value of moderation_flags[:not_moderated], so something still does not make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the failure it would help to answer the question, but this is what I will say, when you use lambda to evaluate the conditions for a scope, they are evaluated at runtime.  So this is important if your scope does something like use `Time.now`.

I'm not sure why that fails, but if you post a bit more information I'll try to be more helpful.

Comment: This is right, more info in the answer from lain and my comments